# What sizes do I need to specify for icons in a Xamarin Tabbar?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My icon code looks like this:

```
        var settingsPage = new NavigationPage(new SettingsPage())
        {
            Title = "Settings",
            Icon = "settings.png"
        };
```

I saw some mention of different icon sizing and names. How do I handle the possible different resolutions and what sizes and names should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naming should be the same across platforms. If your icon is called `settings.png` it should be called that in both platforms' respective folder structures.

**Android**

For Android I use the Android Asset Studio website to generate my icon in all the required sizes for the Action Bar icons:

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html

You can choose from predefined images or upload your own. When you download them from there you get the images in the required folder structure for Android (all the different drawable folders). Copying those over into your own project should be a simple task.

**iOS**

For iOS there are only 2 images needed, one with a @2x and one with a @3x extension in the sizes below. You put these in the Resources folder of the iOS project.

[image]

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/image-size-and-resolution/
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/custom-icons/

Comment: So there is no image needed for @1x for iOS ?   can you provide a link to the size chart above.  Also I am a bit confused.  Do I need a settings.png, settings@2x.png and a settings@3x.png all in the resources folder?

Comment: The @1x is the settings.png in your situation. It is not added as a suffix. However, it was meant for non-retina devices which would mean < iPhone 4 if I'm not mistaking so most people don't add those anymore. But yes, you need one of each in the Resources folder in your iOS project. I edited and added the link to the chart.

Comment: So what should the size of the settings.png be?  Thanks

Comment: In this case the size in brackets is the size for 1x (25pt). Since the 2x is twice as big that's 50 and 3x is 75pt. Please also consider marking this as the answer/upvoting if it helped you.